# How can I batch convert images to b/w while preserving the folder structure

Tags: 13.04, convert, imagemagick, batch

I want to batch process images but I have a very specific task that I want to do

1. I do not want to change image type
2. I want to make them black and white
3. I want it to create/preserve images and sub folder structure

I did this in Photoshop but it did not preserve folders and sub folder content it just threw every converted file in one directory.

My only hope is Linux :D

Thank you in advance!

You can see different discussion about this here but Basharat Sial worked for me

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2143992

Comment: And the images are in which format: RAW, TIFF, JPEG? Please edit your question with the information.

Comment: @levan Convert images in place or create a new directory structure?

Comment: Do not quite understand what you mean 
what I want is this for example main folder "F1" contains 4 different sub folders "2003" "2004" "2005" and "2006" and all of this sub folders Constantine 100-120 files 
 so what I want is the new black and white files have the same structure as they where I do not care if it will overwrite or create a new folder all I care is them to be black and white and  be in the same folders as they were for example if williams 2003.png was in "2003" I want the new file to be in "2003" as well

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9868/convert-an-image-from-grayscale-to-binary || http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108613/how-do-you-binarize-a-colored-image

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can use `convert` command to convert images to black & white:

```
convert -colorspace GRAY image.png b-w_image.png
```

Where `image.png` is the input image and `b-w_image.png` is output imgage.

Combining this command with `find` we can create a bash one liner to convert all the images found under parent directory.

**How-to:**
Open terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, `cd` to parent/main directory and run the following command:

```
for img in $(find . -iname '*.png'); do echo -n "Converting $img"; convert -colorspace GRAY $img $img && echo ' [Done]'; done
```

It will convert and overwrite all the images under parent directory. I will suggest to test it on some temporary images and if you're satisfied with the results than run it on actual images.

Comment: I think I love you worked like a charm 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

**[-monochrome](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#monochrome)** is an option if you want **binary black and white** (1bit per pixel).

It uses some smart dithering and generates very visible output:

```
convert -monochrome in.png out.png
```

[Before](http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/650137main_pia15416b-43_full.jpg):

[image]

After:

[image]

To maintain directory structure, you will have to script it up as [mentioned by Basharat](https://askubuntu.com/a/293713/52975).