# How can I batch process JPG images to change their quality with Nautilus-Actions?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, gimp, image-processing, nautilus-actions

First of all: Thank you for taking the time to read this and provide some help. Any advice is appreciated.

I am using Nautilus-Actions to add a custom context menu's action to create a copy of a JPG image and reduce its quality (and the file size) while preserving the image's dimensions.

Let's say I have this picture with 2.3 MB (2 261 588 bytes) file size and:

[image: list of image properties shown in file manager]

After opening the file in GIMP 2.8 in order to just export a copy and use the JPG Export dialogue box to reduce the quality of the image to 30%:

[image: image size dialog]

I get these properties in the image copy (251.8 kB (251 797 bytes) file size):

[image: list of image properties in file manager]

I am using Nautilus Actions to batch process a lot of images to reproduce the same behaviour via context menu by selecting a bunch of files in Nautilus, right click on any of these selected files, and choose the proper Nautilus Actions action. The result is a file containing the image in the same dimensions as the original, with less quality of course and the file size is a bit greater (275.3 kB (275 265 bytes) file size) but that's not a major problem for me.

The problem is happening when I try to batch process several image files, which results in the first file name cloned into several file names containing a different image each one. With the properties I set in this set of commands:

[image: Nautilus Actions dialog]

Basically, each Nautilus Action is using these parameters:

**Command:** `convert`

- From (imagemagick)

**Parameters:** `%F.jpg -quality 80%% %F-80q.jpg`

- Which is interpreted as: `convert path/to/file1.mid.jpg -quality=80% path/to/file1.mid-80q.jpg`

**Working directory:** `%d`

So, the result is:

[image: thumbnails]

Here we can see each image processed in a different file but just the first file name is used to assign the new names to the copied files. I want a result like:

```
File1.jpg === File1-80q.jpg
File2.jpg === File2-80q.jpg
File3.jpg === File3-80q.jpg
File4.jpg === File4-80q.jpg
```

And so on...

I have used Phatch to do such tasks but what I want is to just right click on the selected files and process in a single action.

Is it there a better way to do this? or... Can I improve in some way what I am doing already?

Thank you very much for your support.

P.S. I have seen [How can I batch convert images to b/w while preserving the folder structure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293672/how-can-i-batch-convert-images-to-b-w-while-preserving-the-folder-structure) and [Is there a way to batch export SVGs to PNGs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209449/is-there-a-way-to-batch-export-svgs-to-pngs/412583#412583) but I am not trying to run this from a terminal but from a context menu. If I am omitting something in this exercise don't hesitate to let me know! I'll appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

#### Edit

After using [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/611340/9598) I find that solution partially does what I expect.

More specifically it solves the file names problem. Nevertheless, I also expected to get smaller file sizes by running the proper `convert file.jpg -quality 30%` command and it is dropping bigger file sizes as you can see:

[image: file size]

Does anyone know if there's something else I should add to the parameters seen in [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/611340/9598)? I appreciate a lot your efforts to provide help on this issue.

#### Update

I am writing this just to let people know I have seen where the problem was with the compression. The file I was trying to compress was already fully compressed so (as mentioned in [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/611340/9598)):

> The process was just adding overhead without gaining anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `%F` twice in a command like that, because `%F` gets replaced by the names of every file selected. For example, a command of `sh` with parameters `-c 'printf "%%s\n" "$@" > foo' %F %F` will create a file named `foo` with the names of every file selected, twice. Therefore the `convert` command that actually runs is:

```
convert file1.jpg file2.jpg ... -quality 80% file1.jpg file2.jpg ... fileN.jpg-80q.jpg
```

And since the last file is taken to be the output file name, only it will matter.

What you can do is wrap your command in `bash -c` and run a for loop:

```
bash -c 'for i; do convert "$i" -quality 80% "${i/%.jpg/-80q.jpg}"; done'
```

(where I am assuming that all files end with `.jpg`)

In an action, you will have `bash` as the command, and for the parameters:

```
-c 'for i; do convert "$i" -quality 80%% "${i/%%.jpg/-80q.jpg}"; done' - %F
```

You can make this more complicated to handle any extension, at which point you might as well skip Actions and use scripting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, muru! It partially does what I expect. More specifically it solves the file names problem. Nevertheless, I also expected to get smaller file sizes by running the proper  `convert file.jpg -quality 30% ` command and it is dropping bigger file sizes. Do you thing there's something else I should add to the parameters? I appreciate a lot your efforts to provide help on this issue.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo how much bigger? It might be that your pics are already pretty highly compressed - in which case further compression is just adding overhead without gaining anything.

Comment: I've added a gif animation for you to see what happen if I "reduce" the images to be 30% of the original size. Thank you!

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo 89 kB to 90 kB seems about right from what my experiments showed - I compressed a file thrice by 30%, and after the fourth try, its size started increasing. Though this shouldn't happen with lossy format like JPEG, I suppose.

Comment: I dropped my comment (probably) at the moment you was writing your. You're right. The images are compressed enough and doing this is not helping for highly compressed images. My fault. It works like a charm with high definition Images, providing a compressed file for 529.5 kB (529 457 bytes) from an original with 2.6 MB (2 601 524 bytes) file size. Thank you very much for your support, my friend!

Comment: If I copy and paste `bash -c 'for i; do convert "$i" -quality 80% "${i/%.jpg/-80q.jpg}"; done'` in my bash, nothing happens :(.

Comment: @Adriaan nothing's supposed to happen - you haven't passed a list of files to it. This post is for use in Nautilus actions, which will provide the list of filenames as arguments to the command